# How can I implement 508 Compliance (like Aria) for a Timeline Slider made with D3.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, accessibility

I understand the usage of Aria and making applications web accessible.But I have no idea HOW to implement compliance methods for the timeline slider. How would I grab focus of the brush and have it read its data to an assistive technology (like a screen-reader)

This is the [plunk I'm working with](http://https%20://plnkr.co/edit/qMg8hojAD3hjgqiQkpCF?p=preview).

Comment: use two date inputs to set a start and stop point without needing the mouse. you can hide it outside of AT, but it can also serve as a visible indicator of the brush values, which is nice for everyone, especially on smaller screens that lack enough pixels to be precise.

Comment: @dandavis you should write it as an answer;

Answer (score 0):

The first step in creating an object that is usable by a screen reader user is to enable keyboard interaction.

I'm not sure I fully understand the object you're working with but from a keyboard perspective, it looks like it should behave like a listbox that allows contiguous selections.

In a normal listbox, the items are listed vertically.  Your "list" is horizontal.

In a normal listbox, I can use the up/down arrow keys to move the selection within the listbox.  The selection is highlighted.  In your "list", I should be able to use the left/right arrow keys to move my current selection to one of the blocks.  Whether the block is wide, as in the first few segments, or narrow, as in the last segments, doesn't matter.  As I move left or right, the appropriate block is selected.

In a normal listbox, once I have an item selected, I can extend that selection by holding down the shift key while using the up/down keys.  In your "list", I should be able to hold down the shift key while using the left/right arrow keys to extend my selection.  That mimics dragging the mouse with the button held down.

Once you have that working, getting the feedback to the screen reader user is just a few steps away.  One of the easy ways to do this is with an aria-live region.  You could update the text within the aria-live region everytime the selection changes or extends.  The change would be read as you update the text.  The text itself could be hidden from the visual user, or as dandavis suggested with his example, showing the selected range might be helpful for the visual user.